# Nuxt 3 $fetch method doesn't work with golang servers?

Tags: vue.js, go, axios, fetch, nuxtjs3

UPD: you can check this yourself: https://github.com/Rusinas/nuxt-fetch-bug

I know I know this sounds stupid as hell and server language has nothing to do with such problems, but hear me out.

I am trying to load data from my local server using $fetch() (or useFetch, no difference), but I get this error:

```
FetchError: fetch failed ()
```

No any other details provided. Server is running using Golang/Fiber. When I am trying to load the same endpoint via Postman, everything is OK:
[image]

But when I try to load the SAME endpoint in my nuxt 3 application:
[image]

I get this:
[image]

But my golang server logging this as success:
[image]

The more weird thing about all this is that if I run my nodejs version of the exact same server (or any other random API), I don't get any error.

I am pretty sure that my server working 100% correct, but maybe I lost some header or something, which express put automatically? Here is my response headers:
[image]

I also checked nodejs response headers:
[image]

Doesn't seem like problem is there.

I have no idea what is happening and I don't know other methods to retrieve async data on server side in nuxt js. I have installed axios, but it throws random errors and works on client side for some reason, which makes using nuxt meaningless. However, axios can call this endpoint and returns my data, but only in browser (despite I call it in setup function without any hooks). I am thinking to switch career now

Comment: Seeing you solved this, what was the issue? Just ran into this but with a node server.

Comment: @hymair oh, well, my solution was to change endpoint from localhost:9000 to 127.0.0.1:9000. Weird, but helped.

Comment: Mainly a `/etc/hosts` configuration.

Comment: @kissu I am on Windows 

Comment: Still have one, just not the same path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem was that fetch() didn't reconize localhost:9000 for some
> reason, but when I changed BASE_URL to 127.0.0.1:9000 it started to
> work

I had the same error: `FetchError: fetch failed ()`

Changing `localhost` in the url to `127.0.0.1` worked for me.

Writing as a separate answer because some might not find it in the comments.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is odd, hope it will help someone, marked as answer

Answer (score 0):

First I think you are using `$fetch` in a wrong way, as I've seen Nuxt uses `fetch` for example:

```js
const data = await fetch(endpoint, {                                                                         
    method: "GET",  
    mode: "cors"       
})                  
.then(resp => resp.json())
```

And for the server, just enable CORS header on the response, like this:

```golang
// you can replace the asterisk with the clients you want.
c.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

hope I helped :)

Comment: The CORS header is already there.  And using of $fetch is absolutely correct if I want to perform regular GET request. Funny thing about it is that I figured it out.

Comment: The problem was that fetch() didn't reconize localhost:9000 for some reason, but when I changed BASE_URL to 127.0.0.1:9000 it started to work

Comment: Well, it recognized it, since the server got the request and processed it, but after that `fetch()` failed silently for mysterious reason

Comment: I think this might help [https://nuxtjs.org/docs/components-glossary/fetch/](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/components-glossary/fetch/)

Comment: Thanks, but, as I mentioned before, the problem is already solved :) Also, this link is for Nuxt 2, while the question is about Nuxt 3. Fetch here and there works much different